# Model association in a to-do list with shareable list items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

Even after reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and a number of similar questions here on SO, I'm still having trouble visualising which associations I need to include.

Here's what I have so far:

**User**:

```
has_one :list
```

**List**:

```
belongs_to :user  
has_many :list_items
```

**List_item**:

```
belongs_to :list
```

The problem is that I'm gonna need to have the functionality to allow a user to look at someone else's list and add any of their list_items to his/her own list. Meaning a list_item can `belong_to_many :lists`.

Will I need another model to facilitate a `has_many :through` relationship, or am I over-thinking it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are over thinking. You don't need `has_many :through`. If `user` has only one `list`.  He can simply add `list_item` to that `list`. Why do you need `has_many :through`.

To add a `list_item` to user:

```
  def add_list_item_to_user(user, list_item)
    user.list.list_items << list_item
  end
```

That's it.

If you want to access `list_items` using `user` you can do like below:

User model:

```
  has_many :list_items, :through => :list
```

Form this you can access `list_items` on `user`

```
   user.list_items
   user.list_items << list_item
```

You have `has_one` relation so I think you don't need to worry much about `through`. If you really want to use you can do.

Comment: Additionally, I'd like to have stats on how many users have certain :list_items on their :lists, and each user should be able to update the completion status of the :list_item on their :list without changing the status of the same :list_item on another's list. 

Is the above method of association going to allow that?

Thanks!